# How can I prevent data-toggle collapse when clicking a button residing inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a  with collapsible data-toggle in which I then have a button with a onclick-method. How can I prevent the data-toggle from collapsing the div when I press the button? Can I do this on the onclick-function somehow?

```
<div class="row toggle" id="dropdown-detail-@counter" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#detail-@counter">
</div>

<div id="detail-@counter" class="collapse">
   <p>content</p>
</div>
```

and the button:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="idXXX" onclick="buttonFunction(this.id)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" aria-hidden="true" id="idXXX"></span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not stop the button click event from going to bootstrap but what you can do is to stop the propagation of the event, in your case:

```
<button onclick="event.stopPropagation();buttonFunction(this.id);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to

```
return false;
```

in your buttonFunction.

This will prevent the click event from bubbling to parent elements

Or you can even do

```
onclick="buttonFunction(this.id);return false;"
```

Comment: Im afraid that did not work. It seems the bootstrap-data toggle overrides that.